# A Canvas inside JLayeredPane doesn't work in JavaFX (using SwingNode)

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am trying to add a canvas in my `JLayeredPane` which is inside a `SwingNode` (the `SwingNode` is embedded in my JavaFX application) but it is not displayed. On the other side, it is displayed in a `JFrame`.

#### Application Code

```java
public class SwingNodeSample_2 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the top-level container frame
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // Swing's JFrame or AWT's Frame
        JLayeredPane lPane = getjLayeredPane();
        frame.add(lPane);
        //panel.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                // Use a dedicate thread to run the stop() to ensure that the
                // animator stops before program exits.
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });

        frame.setTitle("Canvas is displayed in JFrame");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        launch(args);
    }

    private static JLayeredPane getjLayeredPane() {
        JLayeredPane lPane = new JLayeredPane();
        lPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas() {
            {
                setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                setBounds(0,0,300, 200);
            }

            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillOval(75, 75, 150, 75);
            }
        };

        lPane.add(canvas,0);
        lPane.add(new JPanel() {
            {
                setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                setBounds(300,200,50,50);
            }
        }, 1);

        return lPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Create a animator that drives canvas' display() at the specified FPS.
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            swingNode.setContent(getjLayeredPane());
        });

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Canvas Embedded in JavaFX doesn't work !!");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

#### UI Output

[image: blue rectangle is displayed in both and the canvas is displayed only in the JFrame]

Do you have an idea why `JPanel` works fine for both but not `Canvas`?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html). *"The hierarchy of components contained in the `JComponent` instance should not contain any heavyweight components, otherwise `SwingNode` may fail to paint it."* `Canvas` is a heavyweight component (i.e. not a subclass of `JComponent`).

Comment: Instead of a Canvas, subclass JPanel, and override paintComponent rather than paint.  The first line in your paintComponent must be a call to super.paintComponent.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.  Of course, you could always use a [JavaFX Canvas](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) instead of dealing with the headache of mixing JavaFX and Swing.

Comment: Also, if you have existing code written to the Swing canvas and don't want to go to the effort to port it JavaFX (or it is using some third-party library like jfreechart which plots to the Swing canvas), you can make use of the [fxgraphics2d](https://www.jfree.org/fxgraphics2d/) to have your Swing canvas commands plotted to a JavaFX canvas.  Of course, in most cases directly painting to a JavaFX canvas would be preferred.